# When I update a group-list in bs3 I lose the glyphicon

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my html

```
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" id="lblChoice0" class="list-group-item">zero<i id="0" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a> 
        <a href="#" id="lblChoice1" class="list-group-item">one<i id="1" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="lblChoice2" class="list-group-item">two<i id="2" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="lblChoice3" class="list-group-item">three<i id="3" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="lblChoice4" class="list-group-item">four<i id="4" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
```

[image: Before]

I am changing the text of the group-list with a js ajax read from my database with the following code:

```
    $('#lblChoice0').html(msg.d[0]);
    $('#lblChoice1').html(msg.d[1]);
    $('#lblChoice2').html(msg.d[2]);
    $('#lblChoice3').html(msg.d[3]);
    $('#lblChoice4').html(msg.d[4]);
```

[image: After Missing the glyphicons]

How do I get the glyphicons to stay?

Comment: using the html method will change everything inside the child node since the <i> is inside it gets overwritten I believe .innerHtml will work

Comment: @Andrei html() is jQuery and innerHTML is VanillaJS... But both will have same result.

Comment: split your spans to make the image a different element and change only the span with the text!

Comment: yep just tried it forgot. the best answer is done by @Sam below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$('#lblChoice0').html(msg.d[0] + '<i id="0" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i>');
 $('#lblChoice1').html(msg.d[1] + '<i id="1" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i>');
 $('#lblChoice2').html(msg.d[2] + '<i id="2" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i>');
 $('#lblChoice3').html(msg.d[3] + '<i id="3" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i>');
 $('#lblChoice4').html(msg.d[4] + '<i id="4" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i>');`

OR (and this is probably better):

Make your HTML like this:

`<a href="#" id="lblChoice0" class="list-group-item"><span id="title_0">zero</span><i id="0" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>`

Then in jQuery:

`$('#title_0').html(msg.d[0]);`

Obviously do the same thing for all 5 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you replace the whole content of your `a` which also contains the icons. The easiest is to wrap the text inside another element and change that elements content instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#try').click(function() {
    var msg = {
      d: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    };
    $('#lblChoice0 span').html(msg.d[0]);
    $('#lblChoice1 span').html(msg.d[1]);
    $('#lblChoice2 span').html(msg.d[2]);
    $('#lblChoice3 span').html(msg.d[3]);
    $('#lblChoice4 span').html(msg.d[4]);
  });
});
```

```css
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" id="lblChoice0" class="list-group-item"><span>zero</span><i id="0" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#" id="lblChoice1" class="list-group-item"><span>one</span><i id="1" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#" id="lblChoice2" class="list-group-item"><span>two</span><i id="2" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#" id="lblChoice3" class="list-group-item"><span>three</span><i id="3" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
  <a href="#" id="lblChoice4" class="list-group-item"><span>four</span><i id="4" class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i></a>
</div>

<button id="try">Change</button>
```

I made red boxes to represent your icons.